# AVAudioRecorder close immediately in order to hide red bar of shame

Tags: ios, avaudiosession, avaudiorecorder

I'm currently working on an app which record audio.
Once the app is closed I want that the recording stop but i noticed that when I stop the AVAudioRecorder object in applicationWillResignActive the bar stay red for a while (it happens the same with the shazam app").
Instead I need that red bar disappear immediately in order to avoid bothering the user. Any idea on how can I implement this behaviour?
I tried deactivating AVAudioSession but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your AVAudioRecorder instance to nil after deactivating your AVAudioSession.

Comment: This reduce the time of dismiss but problem still remains for some millisecond